# Как сделать так, чтобы в alert выводились все name? В моём коде - если нажать на name="prim" и name="prim2" то выводит только name="prim2"(value)

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Опрос 8"A"</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="a">a<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim2" value="b">b<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim3" value="c">c<br>

    <div id="descr" style="visibility: hidden">
        <button id="one">Отправить</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var button = document.getElementById("one"),
            value;
        document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
                var target = event.target;
                if (target.tagName != 'INPUT') return;
                if (target.checked) {
                    button.parentNode.style.visibility = "visible";
                    value = target.value;
                }
            }

        );
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                alert(value);
            }

        )
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById("one"),
    value = [],
    input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName != 'INPUT') return;

  if (target.checked) {
    value.push(target.value);
    value = [...new Set(value)];
    button.parentNode.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(value);
})
```

Можно было уточнить этот вопрос в предыдущей теме

Comment: А тут что-то не работает, у меня выводит только последний отмеченный name, а я хотел бы чтобы в alert выводились все name

Comment: @music pleasure, вставил скрин. Всё выводит. Ищите ошибку

Comment: Не хочу тревожить, но если нажать на и b то выводить все буквы, а я хотел, если нажать на a и b, то выведет a,b.

Comment: Конкретно на b выводить первые 2 name, а если нажать по стальным?

Comment: Нет я хочу нажать на b и a и чтобы он выводил a,b, а скрипт выводить a,b,c. Посмотрите на свой код на скрине, вы нажали на b, а вывелось a,b,c, а я хочу чтобы вывелось только b

Comment: нет я хочу нажать на b и a и чтобы он выводил a,b, а скрипт выводить a,b,c. На вашем скрине видно, что вы нажали на b,    а вывелось a,b,c,      а я хочу чтобы выводилось только b

Comment: @music pleasure, так? Проверьте код ещё раз

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите иметь возможность выбрать несколько вариантов, то `radio` - не самый подходящий вариант. Семантически правильнее будет использовать `checkbox`

```js
function getCheckedValues() {
  return Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'))
    .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
    .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
}

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(getCheckedValues())
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="prim" value="a">a
<br>
<input type="radio" name="prim2" value="b">b
<br>
<input type="radio" name="prim3" value="c">c
<br>

<div id="descr">
  <button id="one">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Так вот чего он хотел :) А я всё не мог понять этого бреда )

Comment: Ну я бы хотел с разным radiobutton разным name. Просто мне это не подходит. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: так используйте радио вместо чекбоксов - в чем проблема-то?